# Laravel 7 : array validation messages with wildcard index

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-7

So I have an array of data (not necessary coming from a $request)

```
       $validator = Validator::make($array, [
           '*.client_name' => 'required',
           '*.client_phone' => ['required ', 'regex:/^(0)(5|6|7)[0-9]{8}/'],
       ]);

       $validator->validate();
```

So far, validation messages shows as

```
The field 1.client_name is required
```

I want something like

```
Row 1 : The field client_name is required
```

If I use   `$validator->setAttributeNames($newAttributeNames);`   I lose row number from the wildcard(*) even if I set teh wildcard in the new attribute name.

Also note that I don't want to override messages of all the rules provided by laravel (here are 2 examples but irl I have many rules)

So any idea how to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach I could find so far is inspired from @Tim Welis answer but using loops instead

```
$rules = [
    '*.client_name' => 'required',
    '*.client_phone' => ['required ', 'regex:/^(0)(5|6|7)[0-9]{8}/'],
    '*.age' => 'required | numeric | between:0,100',
];

$messages = [];
foreach($array as $rowNum => $row)
{
    foreach($row as $field => $value) {
        $messages["{$rowNum}.".$field.'.required'] = "Row {$rowNum} : The field {$field} is required";
        $messages["{$rowNum}.".$field.'.regex'] = "Row {$rowNum} : The field {$field} format is invalid";
        $messages["{$rowNum}.".$field.'.numeric'] = "Row {$rowNum} : The field {$field} must be numeric";
        $messages["{$rowNum}.".$field.'.between'] = "Row {$rowNum} : The field {$field} value must be between :min - :max";
    }
}

$validator = Validator::make($array, $rules, $messages);
$validator->validate();
```

The rule message is written only once for all the attributes

Answer (score 1):

An approach I generally use is dynamic validation; from your uploaded input, construct the `$rules` and `$messages`:

```php
$rules = [];
$messages = [];
for($i = 0; $i <= count($array); $i++){
  // Since arrays are 0-based, 0 will be Row 1, etc.
  // If you want index 0 to be Row 0, then just use `$i` below
  $rowNum = $i + 1; 

  $cnKey = "{$i}.client_name";

  $rules[$cnKey] = 'required';
  $messages["{$cnKey}.required"] = "Row {$rowNum}: The field client_name is required";

  $cpKey = "{$i}.client_phone";

  $rules[$cpKey] = ['required', 'regex:/^(0)(5|6|7)[0-9]{8}/'];
  $messages["{$cpKey}.required"] = "Row {$rowNum}: The field client_phone is required";
  $messages["{$cpKey}.regex"] = "Row {$rowNum}: The field client_phone format is invalid";
}

$validator = Validator::make($array, $rules, $messages);
$validator->validate();
```

This discards the wildcards, and uses `0.client_name`, `0.client_phone`, etc etc explicitly, and allows you to construct unique validation messages on the fly.

Comment: Although this solution is working, it's quite painful to write, especially when you have too many attributes and rules. I posted an answer inspiring from your solution

Comment: Perfect! I totally agree; this approach works for a couple, simple validation rules, but isn't the most DRY (don't repeat yourself) solution. I'm glad you were able to come up with something that worked for you :)